# Techniques of proving addition uniqueness in some field

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

I have just begun my first introduction to fields.

For this question, let's use $\mathbb{R}$ as an example. Suppose $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. It must be the case that $x + y$ is unique. As in, $2 + 3$ will yield $5$, and not something else as well.

When we want to show things like the $\vec{0}$ is unique, I'd show that if you have $\vec{0}$ and $\vec{0}'$, then $\vec{0} = \vec{0} + \vec{0}' = \vec{0}'$ by the "assume it's not unique and show a contradiction" strategy.

The problem is, I'm unsure how to prove that $x + y$ is unique. I've tried the same approach, as in assume $x + y$ can yield non-unique elements. For example, let two such non-unique elements be $z$ and $w$. This means:

$$x + y = z$$

$$x + y = w$$

However I don't get anywhere when trying to play around with these equations.

How do I prove uniqueness here (restricting this example to $\mathbb{R}$)? Or how does one go about proving this for any field in general? Maybe a better question is, what strategies are there?

Comment: "$+$" is a "binary operation".  That means by definition and two elements of $F$ my be operated ("combined") together to get an element of $F$.  By definition it is either stated or implied that that result is unique and consistent.  If $x+y$ is an element of $F$ it... is an element of $F$.  It is what it is and it cant be anything else.  So $x+y$ is unique *by definition*.

Comment: Technically speaking, equality is transitive so if $x+y = z$ and $x+y = w$ then .... $z = w$.  If that seems circular ... well it is.   $x+y$ has to be ... something and .... it is what it is..... But in actuality it is part of the definition of $+$.  $+$ is an operation that can combine any to elements and yield an element.  The only way you can $x+y=z$ and $x+y=w$ and *not* have $z=w$ is if sometimes $x+y$ is one thing and sometimes its another... I suppose texts should be (and sometimes are) more explicit that mathematical results are consistant and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, let two such non-unique elements be z and w. This means:
> x+y=z
> x+y=w
> However I don't get anywhere when trying to play around with these equations.

Equality is transitive and *equality* is unique.

If $A=B$ and $B=C$ then $A=C$.

So if $x+y = w$ and $x+y = z$ then $w=z$.

====

That can't be proven and is axiomatic in definition that "$+$" is a *binary operation*.

A binary operation is an operation that takes any two elements and yields as output an element.  And $x+y$ will be .... one element.

If your text doesn't *explicitly* state it, it is strongly implied that as $x + y$ is an element, then... it must have an identity and it must be equal to ... whatever it is equal to.  Just as saying $x \in F$ means that $x$ is a specific element of $F$ saying $x+y\in F$ is saying $x+y$ is a specific element of $F$.  Just as $5$ can not be $5$ and $13$ at the same time of $5$ can not be sometimes $5$ and sometimes $13$, the element that is the result of the binary operation $x+y$ is always one result.

Technically, $+$ is a function  that maps $+: F\times F \to F$.  As a function each possible input (an ordered pair, $(x,y)$) is mapped to exact one (unique) element: $+(x,y) = x+y$ of $F$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $+$ is a function, so if its inputs are the same, its outputs are also the same.